# Google sheets time date format 2016-12-01T10:21:43.000Z not recognised as DATATIME

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Google produces logs with the following time date stamp `2016-12-01T10:21:43.000Z` but sheets will not recognise them as time/date objects.
How can this be done?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 5):

Try this *(where cell `I19` is your ISO 8601 date)*

```
=REGEXREPLACE(I19,"T|\..+$"," ")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert those [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) timestamps to Google Sheets dateserial values with this formula:

`=value( regexreplace(A2, "T|Z", " ") )`

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.