# Generate formula for compare dates and if condition is met, put custom text

Tags: arrays, date, if-statement, split, google-sheets-formula

I'm working with Google Sheets and Google App Scripts<sup>1</sup> for retrieve search results from YouTube - by using YouTube Data API - and write those search results *in batch* on a sheet.

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

> Compare the publish date of the video (*values in "C" column*)
> and compare it with the current *date* (*i.e. today's date*).
>
> If the video was published *today*, then, write *(on the cells in "**E**" column)* the word:
> ***NEW!***, otherwise, leave it blank.

I'm looking for a formula that can be set on the cell - rather than just modifying the script and clear the whole column (*or a range*) everytime the script starts running and rewriting the word if the condition is met<sup>1</sup>.

I tried modifying these formulas shared on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67420739/12511801) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36176351/12511801), but, I haven't figured out how to deal with dates on Google Sheets.

Sample:

| Video_ID | Title | Date Uploaded | Video link | ¿Is New Video? | Desired output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rNp9qmASSlw | Privileged Victim Archetype? ~ Meghan Markle "Archetypes" Analysis | 2022-08-25T04:37:48Z | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNp9qmASSlw |  | ***NEW!*** |
| MkBQXzmyh1A | Did Gary Busey Add 'Horror' to Monster Mania Convention? ~ Gary Busey Case Analysis | 2022-08-24T04:38:19Z | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkBQXzmyh1A |  |  |
| q2QNjccf6hw | 10 TRUE Disturbing & Terrifying Followed Home Horror Stories ~ Scary Stories To Fall Asleep To | 2022-08-25T00:15:01Z | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2QNjccf6hw |  | ***NEW!*** |
| -Imgs5T2A8w | 50 TRUE Disturbing & Terrifying Scary Stories In The Dark ~ Horror Stories To Fall Asleep To | 2022-08-22T03:19:25Z | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Imgs5T2A8w |  |  |
| 2hw4EPZLO_A | evento 12 de agosto pelea 11 | 2022-08-25T12:13:23Z | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hw4EPZLO_A |  | ***NEW!*** |
| LY6unkFL3R4 | evento 12 agosto pelea 10 | 2022-08-23T00:42:16Z | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LY6unkFL3R4 |  |  |
| QHW9wddNJQE | WHEN A SMART NUMERON PLAYERS MEETS A STUPID NUMERON PLAYER | 2022-08-25T00:16:52Z | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHW9wddNJQE |  | ***NEW!*** |
| ol6Yt0TjB0E | WHEN YOUR OPPONENT IS THE MOST DUMB PLAYER EVER IN MASTER DUEL | 2022-08-24T00:00:11Z | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ol6Yt0TjB0E |  |  |
| BisJI5BGloY | WHEN YOU DESTROY A THICC WAIFU BOARD WITH ONE SMALL MONSTER | 2022-08-20T00:05:00Z | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BisJI5BGloY |  |  |

This is the [link of the sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EXq5sSesPASpjSzQcICmv-5e4nlBwLFw10fXHER0cz8/edit?usp=sharing).

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm using GAS for retrieve the data and I want to avoid calling for write/clear cells/ranges from the script due to GAS limitations - (*if the script takes five minutes or more, a timeout exception is raised and the script is interrumpted*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(TODAY()=INDEX(SPLIT(C2:C, "T"),, 1), "NEW!", )))
```

[image]

---

### update:

delete everything in E column and use this formula in E1 cell:

```
={"¿Is New Video?"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(TODAY()=
 INDEX(SPLIT(C2:C, "T"),, 1), "NEW!", "OLD VIDEO")))}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) - I'm testing in my current spreadsheet. I wonder if the formula can be applied to each cell in "E" column or what would be the best approach for handle current and new rows/entries on the spreadsheet - your formula is only applied to E2 cell.

Comment: I've modified your formula as follows: `=IFERROR(IF(TODAY()=INDEX(SPLIT(C3, "T"),, 1), "NEW!", "OLD VIDEO"))` - *old video* is just the template for blank. Did you by any change know if your formula or the modified formula has an impact on performance on the spreadsheet?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes the best way is to not use formula on each cell. also this formula is lightweight so there is no impact on performance. and also with open ranges it will apply for new entries automatically.

Comment: Sorry for not specify before, but, the new entries in the sheet will be added on row 2. This will cause an overwrite error: `Error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in E3`. I was wondering if the formula can be set on a "static" cell or any other way to set this formula.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes delete everything in E column and use this formula in E1 cell: `={"¿Is New Video?"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(TODAY()=INDEX(SPLIT(C2:C, "T"),, 1), "NEW!", "OLD VIDEO")))}`